# Blue color background TabItem when pressed

Tags: android, tabitem

I'm beginner Android programmer. I create a TabView and when pressing any item in tab Items the color should be gray, but it becomes blue. Previously, I encountered this problem at Navigation Bottom Menu. I'm confused. Where is the problem? I've put two screenshots at the end to explain what I want and what is happening.

**This is my layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ثبت نقدی" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="پیامک بانکی" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="نمودار" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="بیشتر" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the images bellow button پیامک بانکی is pressed.

**This is what I want:**

[image: This is what I want]

**This is my problem. I do not know where the blue color comes from.**

[image: This is my problem. I do not know where the blue color comes from.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create customer selector. Go to drawable folder and right click. Then select New->create DrawableResource. Add  the file name as tab_selector. Then add below code to that file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_unselected"/>
</selector>
```

Got to value->color file and add these two colors

```
<color name="tab_background_selected">#991c47</color>
<color name="tab_background_unselected">#4d8e63</color>
```

You can customize these colors based on your preferences.

Then add         app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector" to tab layout view

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
```

Comment: This is not what I want
When you press the Items, the color is blue, not when it is selected.
anyway, if I did not get a good result
This solution can help.

Comment: Thankful
answered!
I removed the <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_unselected"/> and changed the state_selected into state_Pressed!.

Answer (score 0):

That's is probably happening because your accentColor is blue and as you are not setting any other color in your xml android is using the default.

Try this out to setup your ViewPager and TabLayout

```
// Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
PageAdapter pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

// Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

obs: PageAdapter has to be your ViewPager adapter

then in your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/main_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 tools:context=".Activity_Main">


 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_above="@id/tabs"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     android:id="@+id/tabs"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:tabBackground="@color/your_color"
     app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/your_color"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this code but it only changes the background and line below
The first time I enter the program, it works fine, but the next time it gets blue again
Or, sometimes, pressing the buttons quickly turns blue again

Comment: I think the changes should take place on the TabItem instead of the TabLayout .

Comment: @Mehran that's exactly what I wrote. Those 2 parameters should be in the TabLayout also can you post some code from your activity which is hosting that layout?

Comment: Excuse me but I think I misunderstood.
I did this code on the TabLayout and I think that the TabItem should be changed.
I have a bit of English problem. What do you want to do with MainActivity codes?

Comment: I want to know how are you setting up your viewpager and tabLayout, because you don't need that TabItem in your xml.